# After a/the trial that

Tags: difference, articles

I came across the following excerpt in a book about Hitler. Before reading this sentence, the reader had been already informed about the trial that Hitler had faced. Why is, then, this trial referred here as "a trial", even though we know that there was only one and it had been described a few pages earlier?

> After years of frenetic political activity and weeks of a trial that
> had demanded his entire attention, incarceration in Landsberg prison
> offered Hitler a

Answer (score 1):

It emphasizes the kind of situation that he was in - the general experience of a hectic time that maybe you, the reader, can empathize with.

Comment: Similarly you might say "Hitler was greatly affected by World War One, a conflict that changed his life and the lives of many other people." It's not the only trial or conflict, it's just the currently relevant one.